# A call has been made on a garbage collected delegate in VB

Tags: .net, vb.net

I have been using this key hook script i found but I continue to get an error after a few seconds of using it in my program. The error says:

> A callback was made on a garbage collected delegate of type
>   'System.Windows.Forms!System.Windows.Forms.NativeMethods+EditStreamCallback::Invoke'.

```
Public Class Keyboard
    Private Declare Function SetWindowsHookEx Lib "user32" Alias "SetWindowsHookExA" (ByVal Hook As Integer, ByVal KeyDelegate As KDel, ByVal HMod As Integer, ByVal ThreadId As Integer) As Integer
    Private Declare Function CallNextHookEx Lib "user32" (ByVal Hook As Integer, ByVal nCode As Integer, ByVal wParam As Integer, ByRef lParam As KeyStructure) As Integer
    Private Declare Function UnhookWindowsHookEx Lib "user32" Alias "UnhookWindowsHookEx" (ByVal Hook As Integer) As Integer
    Private Delegate Function KDel(ByVal nCode As Integer, ByVal wParam As Integer, ByRef lParam As KeyStructure) As Integer
    Public Shared Event Down(ByVal Key As String)
    Public Shared Event Up(ByVal Key As String)
    Private Shared Key As Integer
    Private Shared KHD As KDel
    Private Structure KeyStructure : Public Code As Integer : Public ScanCode As Integer : Public Flags As Integer : Public Time As Integer : Public ExtraInfo As Integer :
    End Structure
    Public Sub CreateHook()
        KHD = New KDel(AddressOf Proc)
        Key = SetWindowsHookEx(13, KHD, System.Runtime.InteropServices.Marshal.GetHINSTANCE(System.Reflection.Assembly.GetExecutingAssembly.GetModules()(0)).ToInt32, 0)
    End Sub

    Private Function Proc(ByVal Code As Integer, ByVal wParam As Integer, ByRef lParam As KeyStructure) As Integer

        If (Code = 0) Then
            Select Case wParam
                Case &H100, &H104 : RaiseEvent Down(Feed(CType(lParam.Code, Keys)))
                Case &H101, &H105 : RaiseEvent Up(Feed(CType(lParam.Code, Keys)))
            End Select
        End If
        Return CallNextHookEx(Key, Code, wParam, lParam)

    End Function

    Public Sub DiposeHook()
        UnhookWindowsHookEx(Key)
        MyBase.Finalize()
    End Sub

    Private Function Feed(ByVal e As Keys) As String
        Select Case e
            Case 65 To 90
                If Control.IsKeyLocked(Keys.CapsLock) Or (Control.ModifierKeys And Keys.Shift) <> 0 Then
                    Return e.ToString
                Else
                    Return e.ToString.ToLower
                End If
            Case 48 To 57
                If (Control.ModifierKeys And Keys.Shift) <> 0 Then
                    Select Case e.ToString
                        Case "D1" : Return "!"
                        Case "D2" : Return "@"
                        Case "D3" : Return "#"
                        Case "D4" : Return "$"
                        Case "D5" : Return "%"
                        Case "D6" : Return "^"
                        Case "D7" : Return "&"
                        Case "D8" : Return "*"
                        Case "D9" : Return "("
                        Case "D0" : Return ")"
                    End Select
                Else
                    Return e.ToString.Replace("D", Nothing)
                End If
            Case 96 To 105
                Return e.ToString.Replace("NumPad", Nothing)
            Case 106 To 111
                Select Case e.ToString
                    Case "Divide" : Return "/"
                    Case "Multiply" : Return "*"
                    Case "Subtract" : Return "-"
                    Case "Add" : Return "+"
                    Case "Decimal" : Return "."
                End Select
            Case 32
                Return " "
            Case 186 To 222
                If (Control.ModifierKeys And Keys.Shift) <> 0 Then
                    Select Case e.ToString
                        Case "OemMinus" : Return "_"
                        Case "Oemplus" : Return "+"
                        Case "OemOpenBrackets" : Return "{"
                        Case "Oem6" : Return "}"
                        Case "Oem5" : Return "|"
                        Case "Oem1" : Return ":"
                        Case "Oem7" : Return """"
                        Case "Oemcomma" : Return "<"
                        Case "OemPeriod" : Return ">"
                        Case "OemQuestion" : Return "?"
                        Case "Oemtilde" : Return "~"
                    End Select
                Else
                    Select Case e.ToString
                        Case "OemMinus" : Return "-"
                        Case "Oemplus" : Return "="
                        Case "OemOpenBrackets" : Return "["
                        Case "Oem6" : Return "]"
                        Case "Oem5" : Return "\"
                        Case "Oem1" : Return ";"
                        Case "Oem7" : Return "'"
                        Case "Oemcomma" : Return ","
                        Case "OemPeriod" : Return "."
                        Case "OemQuestion" : Return "/"
                        Case "Oemtilde" : Return "`"
                    End Select
                End If
            Case Keys.Return
                Return Environment.NewLine
            Case Else
                Return "<" + e.ToString + ">"
        End Select
        Return Nothing
    End Function
End Class
```

Comment: That's used by a RichTextBox.  I don't see one.

Comment: No there is no RichTextBox in this class.

Comment: I was talking about the error message, not your class.

Comment: I have the TextBox in the second form but i get error in this code i get error here in this section {Return CallNextHookEx(Key, Code, wParam, lParam)}